# Robotframework xpath how to locate element

Tags: xpath, click, href, robotframework, element

I want to click on this element:

```
<a id="welcome" class="panelTrigger" href="#">Welcome Admin</a>
```

but I am not able to locate this element.

I have tried:

```
id=welcome, xpath=//*[@id="welcome"]
```

Click Element or Click Link but it is not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean with not working? Is the Id really unique on the page? Is there an error thrown? Is it a public site that you can refer to?

Comment: when you say you have tried `id=welcome, xpath=//*[@id="welcome"]`, did you try it just like that, with both on the same line? `id=welcome` is all you need in this specific case, assuming the id is actually unique.

Comment: also can you check if element you trying to locate is in frame or visibility attribute set to hidden

Comment: I am using robotframework for testing this website. It is https://www.orangehrm.com/ and I am trying to logout. So after Log in I wanna click on element Welcome admin and after to Logout. But I am not able to click on Welcome Admin. And I tried id=welcome and xpath separately and it is not working...

Comment: are u getting any error?

Comment: Please do not provide updates on your question through the comments. Please use the [edit] functionality to add more details to your original question. This provides additional formatting options as well as no character limit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be fine any of the lines below:

```
Click Link    id:welcome
```

---

```
Click Link    Welcome Admin
```

Based on the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Click%20Link):

> When using the default locator strategy, links are searched using
>   `id`, `name`, `href` and the link text.

So if the ID does not happens to be unique you can still refer to the link by its text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Scroll To Element  xpath  ${element_locator}
Wait Until Element Is Visible ${element_locator}  timeout=30s
Click Element  ${element_locator}
```